# Multiple elements inside a component's render() using for

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to make this `Section` class that is supposed to have a headline and a varying number of paragraphs.

```
export default class Section extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>
            { this.props.title }
          </h1>
        </header>

        {
          for (i = 0; i < (this.props.text).length; i++) {
            <Paragraph text=this.props.text[i] />
          }
        }
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

You can probably tell what I'm trying to do here. The problem is that *this* is syntactically wrong (obviously) and I cannot find any information on how to do something like that properly (bear in mind that I also need to have the preceding `<article>` element).

Can somebody come up with a solution? Any additional information/tips/links would be greatly appreciated as well.

**UPDATE:**
Now I have something like this. It still doesn't seem to render the component right.

```
export default class Section extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>
            { this.props.title }
          </h1>
        </header>


        // The updated block
        {
            this.props.text.map(
              function(t) {
                return (<Paragraph text=t />);
              }
            );
        }

      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a great example in [the React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children):

```
  render: function() {
    var results = this.props.results;
    return (
      <ol>
        {results.map(function(result) {
          return <li key={result.id}>{result.text}</li>;
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  }
```

As you can see, they are here using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to *tranform* their dynamic elements into an array of React components, then inserting the whole thing at once, rather than using a for loop to try to insert them one at a time.

Also note the `key` parameter on the child elements; it's important for React to be able to uniquely identify each child for efficient updates.

Modifying that example to fit your case, we can get something that looks like:

```
export default class Section extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>
            { this.props.title }
          </h1>
        </header>

        {this.props.text.map(function (text, i) {
          return <Paragraph text=text key=i />
        })}
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're really close, this is from the react tutorial, it uses React.createClass, but you can modify that easily:

-You should move the looping of the array up above where you will pass it in
-You should use this.props.map (data is specific to the example) to return your Paragraph component.

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Something like this?         `this.props.text.map(
          function(t) {
            return (<Paragraph text=t />);
          }
        );` It still doesn't render the element, though.

Comment: can you update your code with the new stuff? and the other answers took more time than I did, try that stuff too, its specific to your question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the updated code does work, however it needs a pair of curly braces around the `t` local.

The working code is as follows:

```
export default class Section extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>
            { this.props.title }
          </h1>
        </header>


        {
            this.props.text.map(
              function(t) {
                return (<Paragraph text={t} />); // The added braces
              }
            );
        }

      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

A big thank you to everyone who contributed :)